# forEach how save multi data into MondoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I have a application based on Stripe and MERN stack. My issue is that when I hit endpoint to fetch charges then console.log the result I see an array of charges. Which is good. So I decided to use `forEach` to iterate over them and extract `amount` value. This works.

But..

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    stripe.charges.list({
        limit: 3
    }).then(charges => {
        charges.data.forEach(charge => {
            return newData = new Charge({
                amount: charge.amount,
            })
        });
        newData
            .save()
            .then(charge => {
                res.json(charge)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
})
```

When I using `forEach` to create a record in MongoDB based on my model I only get one record saved in the DB even if I have at least 3 charges in the array. How do I fix that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use one operation instead of multi.
For this: `Model.insertMany` method. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Pseudo-code:

```
const dataForSaving = charges.data.map((charge) => {
  return {
    amount: charge.amount,
  };
});

Collection.insertMany(dataForSaving, (err, docs) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: also worked but at each stage i can call `.save()`??

Comment: Question, becasue in this case it will save data to database as long as i will hit endpoint. charges also have id so i want to also fetch i and you find method to first compare if any of this charges are already in DB if yes not save them but save only new once.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the promises to save each new Charge object in an array and execute all of them with `Promise.all()`.

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    stripe.charges.list({
        limit: 3
    }).then(charges => {
        let promises = charges.data.map(charge => {
            let newData = new Charge({ amount: charge.amount })
            return newData.save()
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(result => {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.error(err);
    });
});
```

EDIT - this same idea can be applied to a more elaborate promise, such as one that saves conditionally based on another async query.  It would look like this in outline...

```
function maybeSave(newData) {
    return db.find(/*a query based on newData */).then(result => {
        return (result)? Promise.resolve() : newData.save();
    });
}

        // and in the loop gathering promises...
        let promises = charges.data.map(charge => {
            let newData = new Charge({ amount: charge.amount })
            return maybeSave(newData);
        });
```

Comment: Question, becasue in this case it will save data to database as long as i will hit endpoint. charges also have id so i want to also fetch i and you find method to first compare if any of this charges are already in DB if yes not save them but save only new once.

Answer (score 1):

```
var charges = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

charges.forEach(function(data) {
db.insertMany(data,function(err,result)){
console.log(result)
}

  // SAVE DB
});
```

It works for each record in array saved to database

Comment: i am thinking about efficiency, maybe not fetch data from strpie but fill database with current charge. it will prevent from when in future DB needs to fetch tons of DATA

Comment: ok thanks ...it's use only correction the data in user..client side and also fetch purpose to use async--await ....